# configuring firebase realtime database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, actions-on-google

Already i have initialized firebase with firebase functions and deployed. I am using fulfillment and i am not using separate server. i am using firebase only, ie. I have developed javascript code and deployed in firebase itself.

Now I want to configure firebase realtime database with this project.

Can I use below sample code?

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
});

// As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("restricted_access/secret_document");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

I have few questions:

1. where to start configuring firebase realtime database?
2. How to get file "serviceAccountKey.json"? since,i am not using separate server.
3. How to get database URL?
4. Did OAuth configuration is required before database?

Answer (score 1):

I believe since V1 you don't need to configure the admin since it takes the config form the server by itself checkout this link for more info  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase_admin

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am using the versions " "actions-on-google" :"^2.0.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1",
    "dialogflow": "^0.1.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.4.1"," how to call this sample in another functions "exports.dbCreate = functions.database.ref('/path').onCreate((event) => {
  const createdData = event.data.val(); // data that was created
});" and what path i have to give in "/path"?